# Amazon AWS S3 file upload. How to set file permissions?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a file using Amazon's AWS SDK (S3), and everything is working fine. Below is my code:

```
final AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials() {
    @Override
    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
        return "...myAccessKey...";
    }

     @Override
     public String getAWSSecretKey() {
        return "...mySecretKey...";
    }
};

final StaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);

final TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);

final Upload upload = transferManager.upload(Config.AWS_IMAGE_BUCKET, "images/" + file.getName(), file);
```

Problem is, whenever I upload something like this, the permissions are not set to public, so I can't use them in my app.

How can I set the file permissions from my code so that it's viewable by public?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a [PutObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) with the [ACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withAccessControlList%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AccessControlList%29) you want when you call [upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.S3ProgressListener%29).

Comment: I am having same problem but if I use putObjectRequest than my device getting freez.for further information please see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923689/device-is-freez-while-set-acl-permission-of-s3-bucket).

Answer (score 0):

Choose appropriate ACL policy when you put file in to the bucket.

It can be one of the following option:

1) ACL_AUTHENTICATED_READ

Allow read access to authenticated users.

2) ACL_PRIVATE

Allows only private access to the file.

3) ACL_PUBLIC_READ.

Allows public read access to the file.

4) ACL_PUBLIC_READ_WRITE

Allows public read write access to the file when you write files onto the bucket.

Comment: You can accordingly change the syntax.....the point is to use to appropriate ACL policy when you put files into your Amazon s3 bucket